# How to return multiple variables from a function to main method without arrays or loops in C++

Tags: c++, return, global-variables

I am required to call an input method and a calculations method from main. Input will prompt the user to input 3 variables. Without using arrays, loops, or globalized variables, how can I return the 3 variables back to main to be passed as parameters to the calculations method?

Comment: Can you use a tuple?

Comment: You can use structs, classes, pointers or references.

Comment: See [Functions with multiple return values](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/487/functions-with-multiple-return-values#t=201607221623251363519).